# Remove everything after constant using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got XML that has additional information, BLAH, in each tag.  When creating the tags, I've separated the extra info from the tag name with a constant (`XMLSPLIT` as constant `XML_SPLITTER`)... I needed to do this because I'm generating my XML from a JSON object and I can't have multiple keys that are the same thing... but in the XML output, can't have that superfluous stuff.

For example:

```
....
<SetXMLSPLITBLAH>
    <Value>9</Value>
    <SetType>
        <Name>Foo</Name>
    </SetType>
</SetXMLSPLITBLAH>
...
```

So, after generating the XML, I go through and clean it.  I'm trying to do it with a regex.  I figure, I want to remove anything on a line after the splitter and replace it with just the `>`.

```
let reg = new RegExp("<Set"+XML_SPLITTER+"(.*)\/g");
cleanXML = dirtyXML.replace(reg, "<Set>")
```

This fails to work.

I will note, that I `reg = /<Set(.*)/g;` and that worked just fine... but it also captures "SetType" and any other use of a tag that starts with "

Comment: Use a parser please. [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3600709)

Comment: The meaning of the XML tags in this instance don't matter... I just need to find a way to change one string to another...  As far as the question is concerned, it doesn't matter that it's XML, HTML, or Lorem Ipsum for that matter...

Comment: That clears it a bit; is the `XMLSPLITBLAH` portion always uppercase?

Comment: The `XMLSPLIT` text comes from the constant `XML_SPLITTER`.  The stuff that comes after will be a mix of alphnumerics (upper, lower, numbers).  I really just need to remove everything between a constant (`XML_SPLITTER`) and a `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `^` is a Regex special character that indicates "beginning of line". You'd need to escape it like `\^` for this to work. Something like `/<Set\^\^[^>]*>/g` should do the trick.

Small note: The above regex assumes that the "BLAH" string in your example will never contain the `>` character... but if it does, then your XML is super malformed anyway.

Comment: I can just change the XML_SPLITTER to "XMLSPLIT" so as to avoid any special characters.  I then have the regex  ...   built like this: `reg = new RegExp("<Set"+XML_SPLITTER+"[^>]*>\/g");`  It doesn't seem to work.  Help?

Comment: You can't put the global flag inside the string like that. Correct way is `new RegExp("<\/?Set"+XML_SPLITTER+"[^>]*>", "g");` See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fouzrk6h/

Comment: Oh, whoops, created a slight bug. Fixed the code to `reg = new RegExp(XML_SPLITTER+"[^>]*>", "g");
cleanXML = dirtyXML.replace(reg, ">");` and updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zcnkt7qs/. That should work.

Comment: My hero.  That worked.   I had spit out the reg as a string and saw it had an odd extra trailing slash.  Your switch fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.*` will match `>` and if - for some reason - your XML file is not broken up into multiple lines (i.e. minified), you'll match more than you should. To avoid this, you can use `[^>]*` to match everything up to the `>`.

Since you've gracefully included a *splitter*, it'll make matching much easier and much more predictable (as you mentioned, you match `SetType` without a splitter).

Without a splitter, you'd have to use a regex pattern that resembles `<Set(?!Type>)[^>]*` or `<Set(?!(?:Type|SomethingElse)>)[^>]*` if you had more than just one suffix to `Set` that should remain. These methods use a negative lookahead to assert what follows does not match.

```js
var str = `<SetXMLSPLITBLAH>
    <Value>9</Value>
    <SetType>
        <Name>Foo</Name>
    </SetType>
</SetXMLSPLITBLAH>`

var XML_SPLITTER = 'XMLSPLIT'
var p = `(</?)Set${XML_SPLITTER}[^>]*`
var r = new RegExp(p,'g')
x = str.replace(r,'$1Set')

console.log(x)
```

Comment: This also works.  Thank you for the additional explanations!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this suffers from the same bug my answer previously did -- you're replacing instances of `</Set` with instances of `<Set` (for example, look at before-and-after of last line of example XML). This malforms the outputted XML by erroneously making every closing element an opening element.

Comment: @DeclanMcKelvey-Hembree Thank you, fixed.

Comment: It seems to me (perhaps I'm wrong) that if I'm just concientious about using XML_SPLITTER, I should be able to just grab everything from that constant out through the next `>` and take care of everything.  For example: `let reg = new RegExp(XML_SPLITTER+"[^>]*>", "g");`

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing in my fiddle. @ctwheels' solution of using capture groups is also totally valid though. Depends on whether you want it to work on Set XML elements with XMLSPLIT only or all elements with XMLSPLIT.

Comment: @lowcrawler yes. You don't even need the `>` at the end of the regex since it will stop there anyway. If you don't care about it being explicitly `<Set`-prefixed tags, you could simply use `${XML_SPLITTER}[^>]*`; if you wanted to add support for `/>` (self-terminating tags) you can change it to `${XML_SPLITTER}(?:(?!\/?>)[^>])*` as seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/qCXNMg/1)